# Streamlit AttributeError: st.session_state has no attribute 'processComplete'

Tags: python, streamlit

**Description of the Problem**:
I'm working on a Streamlit app for document processing and chat integration with OpenAI. I've initialized the `processComplete` attribute in my code, but I'm encountering the following error:

```
AttributeError: st.session_state has no attribute 'processComplete'
```

**Relevant Code**:
Here's the relevant part of my code where I initialize the `processComplete` attribute:

```py
# Relevant code section where processComplete is initialized
if "processComplete" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.processComplete = None

# ... other code ...

if  st.session_state.processComplete == True:
    # ... code that uses processComplete ...
```

**Steps to Reproduce**:
I expect that after initializing the processComplete attribute, it should be available for use. However, when running my Streamlit app, I encounter the error mentioned above.

**Attempts and Research**:
I've tried various approaches to resolve the issue, including ensuring that the attribute is initialized before use. I've also consulted the Streamlit documentation regarding session state initialization, but the error persists.

**Expected Outcome**:
I expect that after initializing processComplete, I should be able to access it without encountering an AttributeError.

Comment: note: iam facing the error when i debug the code

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize it this way:

```py
if "processComplete" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["processComplete"] = None
```

Comment: if "processComplete" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["processComplete"] = None         not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the reason is due to the failure to initialize the processComplete attribute, but rather to the rerun mechanism of st. In some special cases, such as manual stop, the st.session_state will temporarily be empty, which I have encountered before. So, you should look for a solution from other parts of the code.

```py
if "processComplete" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.processComplete = None

st.write(st.session_state)
```

Running the above code can reveal that the processComplete attribute has been successfully initialized, and the problem lies elsewhere, possibly due to a bug in st or other reasons.